# Where can I book a flight for scientific experiment to 100 km high?

Tags: launch, rockets, experiment

I have just been wondering if is there any company in Europe which launch scientific experiments into an altitude of about 100 km?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for shopping recommendations (a quickly-outdated, overly-broad list of incomplete answers that aren't well explained and are voted on for reasons other than expertise).

Comment: There is no such thing. You may contact NASA or Roskosmos for some experiment on the ISS. It will be done by astronauts. It won't be cheap.

Comment: Take a look at PLD space company

Comment: I don't see it so much as off-topic as per the Space Exploration guidelines but it does seem poor as per Nathan Tuggy's comment.  You could rephrase it as "which vehicles are capable of sub-orbital flight" but again that's a list.  It may help to look on google or wiki for sub-orbital launchers to begin to work out which are currently operating.